# Excel 2007 INDEX/MATCH using MIN on multiple IFs

Tags: excel-formula

I've searched here and elsewhere for a solution to my problem. I've tried using different versions, including testing subsets, of the formula below, but have had no luck. I hope you can help me. This is for my personal use at home, as I'm now retired.

I'm using Excel 2007 on Win10. In a specified date range (subset of larger spreadsheet covering more dates before and after), I want to find the date the lowest electricity (kwh) usage occurred, but higher than a minimum of 9), but also only that measured for a 24 hour period. In this formula:

{=INDEX(A3934:A4966,MATCH(MIN(IF(C3934:C4966>9,IF(E3934:E4966=24,C3934:C4966))),C3934:C4966,0))}

Column A is Date, C is usage, E is time (expressed as a number, e.g., 22.75, 24.00, etc.)

Note: I'm not using named ranges

Excel finds a date of correct minimum usage, but the date has a time of less than 24 hours! (there are several dates with the same minimum usage, but only a couple for a 24 hour time period. It seems to work on a 20-day range of data, but if I expand it to the above range, it doesn't. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my formula (or approach)? I've tried reversing the usage and time criteria, but it made no difference (I didn't expect it to). Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is solved....

{=INDEX(A3934:A4966,MATCH(MIN(VALUE(REPLACE(C3934:C4966,1,20,MIN(IF(E3934:E4966=24,1,99)*IF(C3934:C4966>9,C3934:C4966,99))))),C3934:C4966,0))}

I used 99 to have a higher number and exclude it from MIN function.

Comment: Thank you, Salvador, but it gave the same date my formula did, one which had a time of 19.5 hours. The minimum value was correct, though.

Comment: Can add a printscreen with the data and the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for your help Salvador, but I guess I'll give up. I can't seem to get the subclauses in my formula to work either. I don't know why; I didn't think my data itself is complex.